# Is a Mezuzah an Angel?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, malach-angel, mezuzah

While reading Tehillim 119:164 commentary on " שֶׁ֣בַע בַּ֖יּוֹם הִלַּלְתִּ֑יךָ ", the interlinear Schottenstein Edition stated :

> Midrashically this also refers to seven mitzvos with which God surrounds the Jewish man every day - tefillin on his head, tefillin on his arm, four tzitzis on his garment, **and a mezuzah on his doorpost** (Menachos 43b). These gifts are truly a cause to praise God because **they serve as constant reminders to remain loyal to Him, and are thus the 'angels' which God has assigned to protect those who fear him.** (ibid.; Rambam, Hil. Mezuzah 6:13).

**Is a Mezuzah really considered an Angel?**

Comment: The Rambam's view on angels differs significantly from the traditional one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't call the Mezuzah an angel as it is not a spiritual being.

The [Kiryat Sefer](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tefillin%2C_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.6.13?lang=bi&with=Kiryat%20Sefer&lang2=en) on the above cited Rambam writes:

> כל מי שיש לו תפילין בראשו ובזרועו וציצית בבגדו ומזוזה בפתחו מוחזק הוא שלא יחטא שיש לו מזכירים רבים והם המלאכים המצילים אותו מלחטוא שנאמר חונה מלאך ה' סביב ליראיו ויחלצם:
>
> *All those who have tefillin on his head and forearm, and Tzitzis on his garment and a mezuzah on his door, strengthens him so that he does not sin, **so that he has many reminders and they are the messengers that save him from sinning** as it says "The angel of G-d camps around those who fear Him and protects them."*

Therefore, I think it would perhaps be fair to view these articles as more of a G-d send (messengers and not angels), a heavenly reminder to act in the correct way befitting a Jew.

One has to be careful not to make the Mezuzah into an object that one views purely as a protective amulet and forget the source of our ultimate protection - G-d. Indeed the Rambam (Maimonides) writes earlier against this sort of belief.

He writes in [Hilchos Mezuzah 5:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tefillin%2C_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.5.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> *It is a common custom to write [God's name,] Shad-dai, on the outside of a mezuzah opposite the empty space left between the two passages. There is no difficulty in this, since [the addition is made] outside.*
>
> *Those, however, who write the names of angels, other sacred names, verses, or forms, on the inside [of a mezuzah] are among those who do not have a portion in the world to come. Not only do these fools nullify the mitzvah, but furthermore, they make from a great mitzvah [which reflects] the unity of the name of the Holy One, blessed be He, the love of Him, and the service of Him, a talisman for their own benefit. They, in their foolish conception, think that this will help them regarding the vanities of the world.*
> (Touger Translation)

So in conclusion, we view the mezuzah as a clear visual reminder to act in the correct manner, knowing that if we do, Hashem (and no-one else) will protect and help us.

Comment: Note that people can also be called malachim: וישלח מלאך ויציאנו ממצרים (במדבר כ:טז ורש״י שם).